# MySQL+Java webService+Android client: Is is better to make multiple queries or one big?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, web-services

I'm creating android app using REST webservice wrote in Java and MySQL db.
In app, I have a list of some items, which have ID's referencing to entries in db. 
Is it better to run a loop and inside get needed info from Mysql (1'st case) or get the info in one big query and then just assign entries to objects?

Examples:

1. Multiple queries (in a loop):
   SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = i
2. One query:
   SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id IN (i, i+1, i+2)

Right now I'm using first option, but I thought it must be quite inefficent to go to same website tens of times (REST)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just test it?

The question you need to ask here: Is database call more time consuming than an operation done in memory? The answer is generally yes. So it's logical to make as less database calls as you can.

Answering your question, second "example" of yours is faster.